# Can't print a method with es6 class

Tags: javascript, standards, es6-class

Why does the code below not produce an output when logging `showInstall`

```
class crud_actions {
    constuctor(second){
        this.allitems_colection = 'main',
        this.allitems_example = second
    }
    listall() {   return  this.allitems_example;    }   
}

var test = new crud_actions('solo');
var showinstall = test.listall();

console.log(showinstall);
```

Comment: You have a typo in `constuctor`

Comment: Oh yes - "constuctor" vs "constructor".